# How do I create filters for custom post types?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

Sorry the question might not make sense. I basically have a custom post type called "Projects" and I need to create a way to filter attributes of the project like "name", "type", etc.

For example if I have a project type called airplane, and another project type called airplane. I would want to be able to search for all projects with the name airplane, and display those in the loop.

I have looked into Taxonomies, but I do not know how to use them effectively.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I did it. If you have your custom post type as "projects", and your category as "airplane".

If you're not planning on using the pre-build loop you would make another one called loop-projects.php. However, it's not necessary.

```
               <?php
                $args = array(
                    'numberposts'    => 5,
                    'post_type'      => 'projects',
                    'category_name'  => 'airplane');
                query_posts( $args );
                get_template_part( 'loop', 'projects' );
                wp_reset_query();
              ?>
```

Comment: ok i don't know exactly how to setup categories

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your description right, structure goes like this:

- `custom post type` *Project*;
- *Type* is `taxonomy` associated with *Project* `CPT`;
- *Airplane* is `term` in *Type* `taxonomy`.

In current WP version you can query for this like (but will get changed in WP 3.1):

```
query_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'project','type' => 'airplane' ) );
```

See [Taxonomy Parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#Taxonomy_Parameters) in Codex.

Answer (score 0):

Simple as this:

```
// default filter:  
apply_filters( 'your_filter_name', $val_to_filter );  
// or, make it more specific:   
apply_filters( 'your_filter_name_'.$val_to_filter, $val_to_filter );
```

You can add this somewhere before your register_post_type call, so it would look like this:

```
// assuming, you got an $args array to make it easy to handle:  
$args['name'] = apply_filters('your_name_filter', $args['name'] );  
$args['name'] = apply_filters('your_name_filter_'.$args['name'], $args['name']);  
$args['type'] = apply_filters('your_type_filter', $args['type']);  
$args['type'] = apply_filters('your_type_filter_'.$args['type'], $args['type']);    
$name = $args['name'];    
unset($args['name']);  
register_post_type( $name, $args );
```

Comment: Mpf. Misunderstood you. "Filter" is a biased term in "wordpress language"..

Comment: Biased? How so?

Comment: Maybe biased is not the right word (learned it yesterday). I meant with "filter" you would normally associate filters like in the answer above `apply_filters`.